# Google Play Store mobile payment

Tags: google-play-store

I'm haing a problem with google play store from few weeks, I can't purchase any app with carrier billing option.
it says "Your mobile payment service isn't available, try again later" any ideas how to fix this?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Carrier billing agreements are only set up on a few carriers in a few countries.

As of the end of 2013, that list is:

```
Country       Carriers                   
Australia     Telstra                    
Belgium       Mobistar                   
Germany       T-Mobile International, o2 
France        SFR, Bouygues, Orange   
Hong Kong     3                       
Ireland       3, O2                   
Italy         Wind Italy              
Japan         Docomo, KDDI, Softbank  
Korea         KT, SKT, LGU+
Netherlands   KPN          
Norway        Telenor      
Poland        Play         
Russia        Beeline      
Singapore     Singtel      
Spain         Movistar     
Sweden        3, Telenor SE
Switzerland   Swisscom
UK            T-Mobile International
US            AT&T, Sprint, T-Mobile, Verizon
```

([source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651410))

If you're still having trouble, [Google Play Support has some other troubleshooting steps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/167794) you should try:

If you don’t see a carrier billing option under Payment options, here are some troubleshooting tips:

- Make sure you’re connected to your carrier’s mobile data network (3G/4G), not Wi-Fi.
- Direct carrier billing is only available on mobile devices using the  Google Play Store
- Google Play Store app, not computers.
- Your account with your carrier must be in good standing.
- Check with your carrier to make sure:

  - You haven’t exceeded your carrier’s monthly spending limit.
  - Your device and service plan allow premium content purchases.
  - Your device can use direct carrier billing.

Comment: Made a suggested edit- T-Mobile is now part of EE, who do not allow use of carrier billing service. 3, however, do. (UK only - I don't know for other countries)

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is working normally otherwise (that is, you can make calls and send/receive texts normally), then it's unlikely to be a problem you can fix yourself. You should contact your carrier or Google support.

Comment: i've tried to contact google and my operator no one has a solution for this. and i'm not the only one that having this problem also my friend has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this has to do with the tie up for billing between your carrier & google. Currently google may not have a tieup with your carrier to charge you directly on phone bill. Or if you were earlier use to but via your carrier than their is a fair chance that contract between google and you carrier is over or in some dispute due to which direct carrier billing integration has been removed.

Comment: the problem is no one says anything, i tried to contact google support they say to talk with the carrier and the when I called carrier customer service they don't know even what is the carrier billing. lol, at this point Im gonna recharge my debit card.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this for a couple of weeks recently until I found help online.  I just needed to turn my wifi off and use my data to make the purchase.  As soon as I did that I was able to use the bill your cell provider option.

Comment: Linking on line source would add value to your solution

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't set up a Google Wallet account, you’ll need to create one before making a purchase.

Open the Google Play Store Google Play Store app.
Select an app or digital content item.
Touch the price.
If you're purchasing an app, review and Accept permissions to continue.
Next to the price, touch the Down Down arrow.
Touch Payment options.
Touch Carrier billing Enable carrier billing.
Review and Save your account information.

Comment: The OP seems to be aware of this option. However, his question is specifically about carrier billing - a separate thing from Google Wallet.

Comment: Actually, according to [Google Play Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/167794) a Google Wallet account is a pre-requisite.

Comment: @Krampus Oh wow, I was not aware of that.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Google wallet. I never had wallet and I've used this payment method at least 20 times over the last 2 months that i've had the phone, and now it's not available. I pay my bills so there's something else going on, especially if more than one person is having the same issue.